# how to check if product contains variants in Liquid

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm trying to write an If statement that says:
if product has this certain variant then show this html.

i tried using this:

```
<% if variant.options contains 'Material1' %>
   <p> Show this. </p>
<% endif %>
```

above code does nothing, can somebody explain why is this not working?

thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you accessing the `variant` object?

Answer (score 0):

You are are wrapping your code in `<% %>` (ERB) instead of `{% %}` (Liquid).

The proper way to loop through product variants and check for an option in a variant, would be something like this:

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
  {% if variant.options contains 'Material1' %}
    {% comment %} Do something! {% endcomment %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Here are the docs for the [variant object](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/variant/).